# UWP: MediaCapture Access Violation since Windows Update

Tags: javascript, uwp, html5-video, winjs, access-violation

Since the latest Windows Update (1703) the Windows.Media.dll always throws an exception when I try to display a camera preview using a HTML5 video tag that was originally working.

The whole error states the following:

**Unhandled Exception at 0x00007FFFFCB8FA2F (Windows.Media.dll) in WWAHost.exe: 0xC0000005 Access Violation reading location 0x0000000000000000**

Further debugging the WWAHost process yields following information:

**"this", "__pThis" and "hr" --> the variable was deleted during optimization and is not available** (rough translation, my VS 2017 is german)

and

**Source not found "previewsource.cpp"**

Trying to disable the optimization using the /Od option did not work.

An issue in the Microsoft Windows Universal Samples GitHub (https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples) states that this problem is related to calling the play method of a HTML5 video tag.
The problem even exists when running the provided CameraAdvancedCapture example though it was updated in respect to the Windows Update 1703 just recently.

CameraCaptureUI is still working but does not allow to select a specific camera on initialization so I have to rely on MediaCapture. Is there an alternative way to display a preview without HTML5 video in a JavaScript web app or are there any other workarounds? Will this be fixed in the future?

Comment: I absolutely don't know these windows specific technologies, so excuse me in advance for any silliness in my comment, but does the [gUM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) API works?

Comment: tested it and gUM API works just fine but is not the best way to go for my purpose... At least it's an appropriate alternative until Microsoft resolves the issue (?)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Please Take a look at this: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/601d9974-b184-4a36-a877-8a07d6787a94/uwpjs-all-javascript-apps-using-camera-preview-will-crash-after-latest-windows-update?forum=wpdevelop